# SearchView doesn't start search activity

Tags: android, xml, searchview

I'm trying to add a search activity using a search view in the searchbar. I've seen a few questions like this but I've tried all the answers and nothing works for me. The search show properly but when I after I type in the search phrase and click search nothing happens.
My Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.y2apps.quoteformessenger.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable" android:value=".SearchResultsActivity"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" android:value=".SearchActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".SearchResultActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
                <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

the searachable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

the styles.xml file

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

The main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager =
               (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                    searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "can't find search bar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and the search activity

```
public class SearchResultActivity extends Activity {
    // ===========================================================
    // Public Constants
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Private constants and Fields 
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Constructors
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================
    // Public methods
    // ===========================================================
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }
    // ===========================================================
    // Private methods
    // ===========================================================
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "YARON YOREH 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            Toast.makeText(this, "YARON YOREH asked for " + query, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //use the query to search your data somehow
        }
    }
    // ===========================================================
    // Inner and Anonymous Classes
    // ===========================================================

}
```

if it helps to diagnose this, the search hint isn't showing up either.
thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" android:value=".SearchActivity" />
```

I believe it should be:

```
 <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" android:value=".SearchResultsActivity"/>
```

However, you shouldn't need since you already define the default searchable globally for your application

Answer (score 0):

According to your code , what i understood is your MainActivity is the search activity and you want to display the result in new activity. For that you have to make MainActivty as searchable.Change your manifest like below.
    Main Activity for performing search

```
     <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
           <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
```

Activity to display results

```
        <activity android:name=".SearchResultActivity" ... >

        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                   android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Comment: Thank you Gautam for you answer but my main activity is the main activity that has the search bar and search activity is my search activity. My problem was the typo as mentioned below. But thank you for taking the time to read it